# Comunicar programa python con aplicación Android

Tags: python, android-studio

Tengo que hacer que se comuniquen un programa escrito en Python con una aplicación creada con Android Studio, me recomendáis algún método?

Me han hablado de servidores teniendo cliente proveedor pero no sé si es lo mejor.

Si sabéis de sitios donde pueda encontrar información también lo agradecería, cualquier información que tengáis me es útil.

Gracias.

Comment: La descripción es demasiado vaga, pero sí, una solución típica sería escribir en python un _backend_ que soporte el protocolo HTTP (para ello puedes usar Flask, Django, o FastAPI, entre otros) y en el cliente Android hacer peticiones HTTP (usando por ejemplo retrofit) a las URLs expuestas en el backend, para enviar u obtener datos. Naturalmente hay muchas otras posibilidades y soluciones, pero sin más detalles....

Comment: Podrías usar sockets (Si esta hecha en java) Java, JavaScript, C, Python y otros soportan Sockets (Servidores) es una buena alternativa si vas a tramitar datos, también una API pero me parece mas factible lo de los sockets ya que solo tendrías que abrir y cerrar los puertos antes y después de lo que sea que hagas